# Removing iCloud from my PC

Tags: icloud, desktop

I keep getting a message on my PC that my iCloud is almost full.
I moved the photos on my phone to my computer by cable and store it in my photos.

Can I remove iCloud from my PC, and still keep it on my iPhone and iPad?

If I remove it from my computer, will I still be able to keep iCloud on my iPhone5 and my iPad2?

I want the photos to work between my iPhone and iPad2 only.

I can email my photos I take with my phone to my computer or I can connect it to a cable and just download it directly right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can remove iCloud from your PC if you don't want it there anymore.  You won't be able to access any of your iCloud files or photos directly on your PC anymore.  If you need any file/photo from iCloud on your PC, you can go to iCloud.com in your browser.  From there you can access everything in iCloud just like it was on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

If your iCloud storage is almost full, removing the program from your computer won't help you.  Deleting the program on a PC won't affect the storage. You need to remove files from iCloud itself.

For example, last time my storage was full, I copied all of my pictures out of iCloud and then deleted the originals to free up space. This is simpler using the Mac Photos app; I'm not sure what the best way to do this on a PC would be.